# How to format a table with many Mathematical or text entries in a double-column document?

Tags: pdftex, latex-2.09

I am working on a table with many mathematical or text entries in a double-column document. I can generate some output but the look is not good. I need your help to kindly improve the formatting of this table for a better looking output. My LaTeX code for generating the table in the paper is enclosed below.. I thank you for the great help.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Characteristic Exponents of Three Dynamical Systems}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3 cm}|p{0.8 cm} | p{0.8cm}| } \toprule
  System & Characteristic Exponents (CEs) & MCE Value & $D_{KY}$ \\ \midrule
  Dynamical System   (1) & $CE_1=0.0833$,   $CE_2=0$,  
   $CE_3=-0.6987$ & $ 0.0833$ & $2.1192$ \\
    Dynamical System (2)  & $CE_1=0.1344$,   $CE_2=0.0280$,
   $CE_3=0$, $CE_4 = -1.1499$  & $0.1344$ & $3.0456$  \\
  Dynamical System (3) & $CE_1=0.1544$,   $CE_2=0.0380$,
   $CE_3=0$, $CE_4 = -1.1499$  & $0.1544$ &$3.0625$  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{Table-CE-Values}
\end{table}
```

I have enclosed the output of my LaTeX document (this Table segment) as an iamge file - Kindly help me to improve the code for a better output. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document.  With your fragment we cant see what is wrong with your table. Use of `booktabs` rules is not intended  for use in tables with vertical rules ...

Comment: Regardless of other considerations, the caption and first two columns would look nicer ragged right with no hyphenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One of the main formatting criteria of any well-edited document is to make sure that a table's width is no larger than `\columnwidth`. To meet this objective, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and set its target width to `\columnwidth`.
- To maintain a sufficient degree of legibility, I suggest you display but one value of `CE` per row.
- Do give the table a more open look by omitting all vertical rules. And, since you employ the `booktabs` package, do replace interior `\hline` directives with `\addlinespace`.
- Last but not least, be sure to "snug up" the letters `C` and `E` that form an abbreviation for "characteristic exponent". In the code below, this is down via `\mathit`; if you'd rather use upright letters to denote variables, just replace `\mathit` with `\mathrm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,calc,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{% suppress full justification
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % how to display variable names 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Characteristic Exponents of Three Dynamical Systems}
\label{Table-CE-Values}

\smallskip

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} p{\widthof{Dynamical}} L p{\widthof{0.0833}} c @{}} 
\toprule
Dynamical System & Characteristic Exponents ($\vn{CE}$s) & MCE Value & $D_{KY}$ \\ 
\midrule
(1) & $\vn{CE}_1=0.0833$ \newline $\vn{CE}_2=0$ 
      \newline $\vn{CE}_3=-0.6987$ 
    & $0.0833$ & $2.1192$ \\
\addlinespace
(2) & $\vn{CE}_1=0.1344$ \newline $\vn{CE}_2=0.0280$ 
      \newline $\vn{CE}_3=0$ \newline $\vn{CE}_4 = -1.1499$  
    & $0.1344$ & $3.0456$ \\
\addlinespace
(3) & $\vn{CE}_1=0.1544$ \newline $\vn{CE}_2=0.0380$ 
      \newline $\vn{CE}_3=0$ \newline $\vn{CE}_4 = -1.1499$  
    & $0.1544$ & $3.0625$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\lipsum[1][1-2] % filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the full code.. I tested and it runs very well!! 

Answer (score 4):

This code fragment should work:

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Characteristic Exponents of Three Dynamical Systems}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{2-Y}, vlines,
             colspec = {X[0.75, l,m] X[1.25, l, m, mode=math]  *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.4}]}},
             row{1}  = {guard, mode=text, m},
             hspan=minimal
             } 
System 
    & Characteristic Exponents (CEs) 
        & {MCE\\ Value} & $D_{KY}$  \\ 
  
Dynamical System   (1) 
    & \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{CE}_1 & = 0.0833,   \\
        \mathrm{CE}_2 & = 0,        \\   
        \mathrm{CE}_3 & = -0.6987  
      \end{aligned}
            & 0.0833        & 2.1192    \\
Dynamical System (2)  
    & \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{CE}_1 & =0.1344,    \\ 
        \mathrm{CE}_2 & = 0.0280,   \\
        \mathrm{CE}_3 & =0,         \\
        \mathrm{CE}_4 & = -1.1499  
      \end{aligned}
            & 0.1344        & 3.0456  \\
Dynamical System (3) 
    & \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{CE}_1 & = 0.1544,   \\
        \mathrm{CE}_2 & = 0.0380,   \\
        \mathrm{CE}_3 & = 0,        \\
        \mathrm{CE}_4 & = -1.1499  
      \end{aligned}
            & 0.1544         & 3.0625  \\
\end{tblr}
\label{Table-CE-Values}
    \end{table}
```

I will extend it to MWE, when in question you will provide MWE (that you will see how important is to provide MWE and not only some code snippet).

[image]

Comment: What packages do I need to define at the beginning (preamble) to run your LaTeX code? Kindly advise me what should i type under \usepackage{} for this code! Thanks a lot..

Comment: Read my answer. I clearly stated in it, that I will provide complete MWE, when you will do the same in your question. So, please edit it and extend your code fragmnet to complete small compilable document.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar, any news? I still wait on edit of your question ...

Comment: Dear Zarko, this table is part of my research paper (which I submitted and the paper is under Review). I could not post the full paper for that reason only.  Mico gave a code, I tested it, it works beautifully, and I thanked him on the same day. I marked his answer as correct, as it works well for me. I don't know what more I can do! Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar, just provide MWE on the similar way as Mico did in his answer. BTW, I provide a code before him, so what was wrong my code which gives the same (or maybe even nicer) result? Just fact that I just wrote table code and not MWE like you in question? Sorry, but your excuse is worthless.